# Can i Grab the only sound louder than a certain level in html5?

Tags: html5-audio, web-audio-api, getusermedia

I need to catch only sound that louder than a certain level.
Is it possible?

I now about `getUserMedia`, but haven't found any information addressing this scenario.

Comment: Maybe with the WebAudio API, you can do what you need. Take a look ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use Web Audio to detect volume level (I did a code example of this: https://github.com/cwilso/volume-meter), and use that to switch on recording of a sound (e.g. using the relatively new MediaRecorder API, or a library like RecorderJS (https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs).  You'll need to make a bunch of code decisions yourself (like, does it automatically switch off?  What level turns it on?  Instantaneous volume level, or average volume over time?)